# Use nginx to handle errors generated by another server

Tags: node.js, http, nginx

I have an nginx server which handles some requests itself and passes the rest to a Node.JS server using the following lines:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

Both nginx and node.js produce their own http pages, which should be identical (a 404 from nginx should look the same to a user as a 404 from node.js).

I would like nginx to check the response code produced by node.js and fall back to the its own error page if it produces an error. Is this possible or sensible?

```
1. Nginx receives HTTP request
2. HTTP request passed to Node.JS
3. Node.JS responds with 404 error
4. Nginx responds with 404 error
```

Comment: is your node process sending just a 404 or is it sending a body in the response as well?

Comment: You need directives `error_page` and `proxy_intercept_errors`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the line

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

to the location block will cause errors generated by the remote server to be intercepted by nginx.